# indexOf does not work properly in Titanium mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

In Titanium mobile indexOf function of String is not working properly.

```
console.log( "test2".indexOf( /tes/i )  );
```

will always give -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add quotes as it does not support regular expressions, you can only provide strings:

```
console.log( "test2".indexOf( '/tes/i' )  );
```

But in this case it still won't find anything as you are providing a regex. This however will return a result

```
console.log( "test2".indexOf( 'tes' )  );
```

For a regex you might want to use native JavaScript, which is perfectly fine supported by Titanium

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` doesn't take a RegExp argument: it only takes a string. Your regex is turned into a string (`"/tes/i"`), which is then used as the argument to `indexOf`. Obviously this won't find anything in this case.

This is true in all Javascript engines, not just in Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
/tes/i.test('test2')
```